# Use the definition of convergence of a sequence to show $\lim \frac {2n^2}{n^3+3}= 0$

Tags: limits

> Use the definition of convergence of a sequence to show $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac  {2n^2}{n^3+3}= 0$$

I understand that to do this we must show $ \frac  {2n^2}{n^3+3} \leq \varepsilon$, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: If you have access to the Squeeze Theorem, the argument can be fairly short. Do you?

Comment: @alex.jordan preferably use only the definition if that's what the question asks for.

Comment: Actually to be pedantic you would need to specify $n$ in the limit. You probably mean $n \to \infty$, right?

Comment: @mathreadler It can be argued that when $a_n$ is understood to be a sequence (as opposed to a function of real $n$ or some other object), that $\lim a_n$ is unambiguously asking for the limit as $n\to\infty$. But it would come down to convention.

Comment: Yes you are right, I missed the word "sequence" and only saw the word limit ( at the time of reading ! ). Probably the natural numbers are the convention if the word "sequence" is used, I agree there ;)

Answer (score 3):

Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N$ large enough such that $\frac{2}{N} < \epsilon$ so that for $n>N$ we have $$\bigg|\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}-0\bigg|=\frac{2n^2}{n^3+3}\leq\frac{2n^2}{n^3} =\frac{2}{n}< \frac{2}{N}<\epsilon$$